# Translate in real time for a few minutes without pausing

Tags: android, translation

I'm looking for a translation application for Android that could listen a speaker via the phone's microphone for at least a few minutes without me having to click anywhere and translate in real time. I tried Google Translate, Microsoft Translator and Talking Translator on my Pixel 6 running Android 12, but they all stop listening after a few seconds or when the speaker pauses. Any price or license is ok.